# Capturar preço de uma div em C# através do HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, div, html-agility-pack

Amigos, saudações! Sou iniciante em C# e estou tentando capturar o produto com o menor valor através da plataforma 'enjoei' e posteriormente, o mesmo aparecer em uma textbox, por exemplo. O código feito até o momento foi esse:

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc;
    string pesquisarprecoenjoei;

    private async void descobrirprecoenjoei()
    {


        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => web.Load("https://www.enjoei.com.br/camisa-do-flamengo-adidas/s?ref=products_search&sid=9a784ff9-da43-44f4-817c-bf2dedef19bd-1637161303630&q=camisa+do+flamengo+adidas&sr=near_regions&o=low_price"));
        var preco = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='c-product-feed__list']//html//body//main//section//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//span//span");
        var inner = preco.Select(node => node.InnerText);



    }
```

Porém, ocorre o seguinte erro: "System.ArgumentNullException: 'Valor não pode ser nulo.
Arg_ParamName_Name'"

O caminho em XPath é: /html/body/main/section/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]/span[1]

Como proceder? Muito obrigado desde já!

Comment: Tentei alterar pra "//div[@class='c-product-feed__list']//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//span//span" e nada :(

Answer (score 0):

User conforme abaixo para retornar todos os preços da página de pesquisa:

```
var precos = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='c-product-card__price']");
```

Como SelectNodes retorna uma coleção, você precisará iterar pelos resultados usando foreach (por exemplo):

```
foreach (var preco in precos)
{
    var inner = preco.InnerText;
}
```